# Getting list of components with JSP's and Adobe Content Management (AEM)

Tags: jsp, xpath, aem

I am trying to get a list components and print the output on either a drop down menu or row/cells.

I have done the following:

```
<%

//Build query
String query = "/jcr:root/content/foo/";

Query aquery = currentNode.getSession().getWorkspace().getQueryManager().createQuery(query);
NodeIterator result = aquery.execute().getNodes();

while(result.hasNext()){
    Node job = result.nextNode();
    String tmp = job.getPath();


}

%>
```

The get the following error:

```
An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /apps/goarmy/components/templateGenerator/templateGenerator.jsp
Query cannot be resolved to a type
26:     //Build query
27:     String query = "/jcr:root/content/foo/";
28: 
29:     Query aquery = currentNode.getSession().getWorkspace().getQueryManager().createQuery(query);
30:     NodeIterator result = aquery.execute().getNodes();
31: 
32:     while(result.hasNext()){
```

In an code example it had a value called: Query.XPATH used like:

```
Query aquery = currentNode.getSession().getWorkspace().getQueryManager().createQuery(query, Query.XPATH);
```

If I use the above syntax I get the same error and another one saying:

```
Query.XPATH cannot be resolved to a type.
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better, if you post whole jsp page, you are talking about.
Currently it seems, that you have a couple of problems there:

- you've not imported class `javax.jcr.query.Query` and trying to use it. Also, it would be better to include global.jsp, where most on important imports are done;
- [there](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/query/QueryManager.html) you can find correct signature of `createQuery` method;
- looks, like XPATH query you posted is not really valid. Also, from your question it's not clear what do you need to extract. For example, query `/jcr:root/content/foo` will return the only page `/content/foo`. Do you need to get it's child nodes, or?